# A very simple question about Admissible Heurisitcs

Tags: search-algorithms, artificial-intelligence, search-trees, heuristics

Given admissible heuristics f(s), g(s), h(s).

It is true that max(f(s), g(s), h(s)) is still admissible.. but is it still admissible if its max(f(s), g(s) + h(s)). I believe it is not admissible but I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Assume towards contradiction that it is true, then ignore $f$ completely (choose some $f$ which is constant)

Then, what your statement would say is that $h,g$ are admissible $\implies h+g$ is admissible.

In particular, for any admissible function $g$, choose $h=g$, and your statement implies $2g$ is admissible. Apply the statement again to get that $3g$ is admissible, and you can prove using induction that $kg$ is admissible for any constant $k$. However this is clearly not true, since you can choose $k$ to be big enough so $kg$ would over-estimate the search cost. In particular, choose $k=max(cost) + 1$, and then $kg$ would overestimate the cost everywhere.

Therefore its a contradiction and this statement is **false**

Comment: So any value(besides 0 and negative) added to the max will not be admissible since it overestimates the original cost

Comment: Yes, and  you only need to show this for a particular example of your choice.